# what is a 4 socket server? What is "socket" in this context?

Tags: ibm, socket

I see that the [IBM System x3750 M4](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/x/hardware/rack/x3750m4/) is a "4-socket" server. What does that mean? Does that mean that the server has 4 network ports? What is a "socket" in this context?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about basic computer hardware and does not appear to be a questions a system administrator would ask.

Comment: Yeah. I wondered too. "Professional capacity" with no idea what "socket" means these days, when a LOT of software is licensed per socket or per port and socket count / multisocket capability is the core of every mid range server. Me wonders whether this is a superuser that just went to the wrong place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this context a socket is a spot on the motherboard for a CPU. This has room for 4 CPUs total.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_socket

Answer (score 2):

that is cpu socket that you can put cpus in. so it means that you can have up to 4 cpus, though you can leave sockets empty and fewer.